# Python Flask service is not executing all function calls in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, waitress

I am new to Python and I am trying to create a Flask web service.

The service I've created is working fine for serial requests but when multiple requests come, it shows some weird behavior.

In my actual application what I observed is when multiple requests come frequently (one closely followed by another), the other calls wait for the first call to complete and then they execute in parallel.

I tried to reproduce this behavior and I got some success.

Here's the sample code:

```
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve
import datetime
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/get_data/")
def get_data():
    print("Request received at: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))

    file_path = "D:\15MB_Data.csv"
    t1 = datetime.datetime.now()

    data_frame = pd.read_csv(file_path, ",")

    print("Starting processing after reading file at: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    doSomeHeavyWork()

    t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
    init_time = 'Time in Initialization : ' + str((t2 - t1)) + ". Completed at " + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    print(init_time)

    return init_time


def doSomeHeavyWork():
    current_time_plus5 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(0, 5)
    while datetime.datetime.now() < current_time_plus5:
        i = 0
    return 1


serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5002)
```

To call the *get_data* function I use:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5002/get_data
```

And the output of this sample code is:

```
Request received at: 2021-11-10 15:26:32.482249
Starting processing after reading file at: 2021-11-10 15:26:32.875022
Request received at: 2021-11-10 15:26:33.112884
Request received at: 2021-11-10 15:26:33.485669
Request received at: 2021-11-10 15:26:33.804485
Starting processing after reading file at: 2021-11-10 15:26:36.032274
Starting processing after reading file at: 2021-11-10 15:26:36.438055
Starting processing after reading file at: 2021-11-10 15:26:37.089661
Time in Initialization : 0:00:05.444947. Completed at 2021-11-10 15:26:37.927196
Time in Initialization : 0:00:07.936492. Completed at 2021-11-10 15:26:41.049376
Time in Initialization : 0:00:08.023461. Completed at 2021-11-10 15:26:41.509130
Time in Initialization : 0:00:08.302279. Completed at 2021-11-10 15:26:42.120756
```

From the output we see that the second request was received at **2021-11-10 15:26:33.112884**, but it started processing at **2021-11-10 15:26:36.032274** (waiting time 3 secs), and the other calls were also waiting till then.

I am using PyCharm on Windows 10 for development purposes.
I thought it could be due to the development environment so I tried hosting the application on Ubuntu also using NGINX, but still no luck.

What should I do to execute new requests without waiting for the previous ones to complete?

Comment: I guess the other requests were waiting for I/O to complete for the first request. Did you try running the requests on separate threads?

Comment: As far as I know about api's, the requests should automatically run of separate threads. Do we need to run on different threads ourselves in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`waitress` runs requests on a thread pool, defaulting to [4 threads](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/design.html). Since the logs show 4 requests, this isn't the limit.

`doSomeHeavyWork` implements a busy wait with no i/o or sleeps. Due to the [GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython), Python bytecode execution blocks even on different threads (vs. i/o or most low-level libraries). If this were instead doing i/o or calling `pandas`/`numpy` type operations (many, not all of which release the GIL), rather than busy-waiting, the block time would be much less.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Since, the library I am using consuming all the CPU without any i/o, I am facing this issue. To solve this issue I ran multiple processes to utilize all the CPU cores and load balanced them. Also, python Multiprocessing is working for me but I have chosen the load balanced approach as that suits my application. Thank a lot for the answer.